# SLComposeViewControllerResultDone when Facebook password is incorrect

Tags: ios, xcode, facebook

I use the SLComposeViewController to post a facebook message. But the SLComposeViewController result returns **SLComposeViewControllerResultDone** even when the facebook password is incorrect.

Here my code:

```
  SLComposeViewControllerCompletionHandler __block completionHandler=^(SLComposeViewControllerResult result){
    [fbController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

    switch(result){
        case SLComposeViewControllerResultCancelled:
        default:
        {
            CCLOG(@"Cancelled.....");
            [self cancel];
        }
            break;
        case SLComposeViewControllerResultDone:
        {
            [self success];
        }
            break;
    }};
```

The message is not posted with an incorrect password.

How to check if the user is correctly logged or is the message is correctly posted?

Thanks.